# Aggregate COUNT elasticsearch group by logtype

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

My logs have multiple types. Each log type has multiple indices organised by date. Log types share similar fields (which means i can run a single query on multiple log type + indicies to filter out result). I want to get count which matched certain criteria group by "log type".

One way to solve it is to run multiple queries in parallel. Each query is like normal _search query with filter criteria on a single log_type. Then we can get _count in returned. But it would require running multiple queries -- multiple round-trip.

Is there a better way to get the result within a single query only.

-- Below is my simplified mapping --

```
   "logstash-2017.01.09": {
      "mappings": {
         "typeA": {
            "properties": {
                "IP": {
                  "type": "ip",
                  "fields": {
                     "raw": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "COUNTRY": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "norms": {
                     "enabled": false
                  },
                  "fields": {
                     "raw": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }
               }
           }
        },
        "typeB": {
            "properties": {
                "IP": {
                  "type": "ip",
                  "fields": {
                     "raw": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "COUNTRY": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "norms": {
                     "enabled": false
                  },
                  "fields": {
                     "raw": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }
               }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

There is multiple indices such as logstash- (organized by date). I want to find COUNT (group by log-type) for log matching criteria such as country = 'US';

sample response should be something like:

{
 typeA: 30000,
 typeB: 50000
}

or there are 30000 records of typeA which matched 'country = US'; etc...

I am using elasticsearch nodejs client. Below is what i tried:

```
elasticClient.search({
    index: indices.join(","), //['logstash-2017.01.09', 'logstash-2017.01.10'] -- all indices within time interval
    type: logTypes.join(","), //['typeA'] -- run for each type separatedly and in parallel
    body: {
        "query": {
            "filtered":{
                "query": {
                    "query_string" : {
                        "query": 'COUNTRY:"US"' // example only
                    }
                },
                "filter": { 
                     "range" : {
                        "@timestamp" : {
                            "from" : startIso,
                            "to" : endIso
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "from"   : 0,
        "size"   : 0
    }
})
```

Comment: please share your schema mappings/settings and queries you have tried so far

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question with the schema example and query being used.